# Recovering bluetooth device address

Tags: javascript, api, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I need to write a code to get the address of the device, CONNECTING to my site
So, for an instance, I visit my website with my phone. On button click, I need to get the Bluetooth address of it.
I've seen some examples showing how to get addresses of nearby devices. That's not what I need.
I don't have time for a proper research now, so if you have examples, please, share them with me.
I'd really appreciate your help.

Comment: Please show what you tried!

Answer (score 0):

There is this experimental API, but it’s not enabled by default

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/BluetoothDevice

Normally a website can not access such private device information, but apps that a user chooses to install can, such as an app written with ReactNative.